# onTouchEvent, detect ACTION_MOVE if user put down finger outside of control

Tags: android, android-layout

I have my own toggle button with:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    super.onTouchEvent(event);

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

        if (event.getY() >= getHeight()) {
            if(isChecked()) {
                this.setChecked(true);
                this.performClick();
            }
        } else if (event.getY() <= 0) {
            if(!isChecked()) {
                this.setChecked(false);
                this.performClick();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I want detect if user holds his finger across my togglebutton and change it. But if user presses a finger on the outside of the control I can not detect onTouchEvent.
What are the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can register `OnTouchListener` for your view:

```
mOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            final int action = motionEvent.getAction();
            boolean ret = false;

            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                ret = ...;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                ret = ...;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                ret = ...;
                break;
            }

            return ret;
        }
    };
```

What returns by `onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)` method defines that any other OnTouchListener() must audit this event or no.You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933426/android-cant-see-action-move-up-in-ontouchevent-of-a-relativelayout).

**Edit**:
Create `two` OnTouchListener() classes and register each one to observe it's motion events.(one for your `button` and one for it's `parent`).Return `true` in `onTouch` method of class witch audit your buttons motion events,so only this class audit button's motion events and not parents listener.

Comment: i have the same behavior.  How i can detect when finger move across my controll?

Comment: i set OnTouchListener on parrent view where places my toggle button

Comment: the method return View view of my parent layout always